# wp_footer action hook generating error in my WordPress files

Tags: wordpress

I am using beaver builder theme and beaver builder plugin, currently I am creating a new module my own and trying to send all my script code to footer for that my code looks like shown below:

```
<?php function gt_footer_script(){?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        "use strict";

        if ($('#gt-lightgallery_v<?php echo $gt_filter_counter; ?>').length) {
            $('#gt-lightgallery_v<?php echo $gt_filter_counter; ?>').lightGallery({
                selector: '.gt-gallery-box',

            });
        }
        });
    </script>
    <?php } add_action('wp_footer', 'gt_footer_script');?>
```

my function is gt_footer_script but once I run my code it says can't re-declare function `gt_footer_script` its already declared on line number 110, while its first function created i am otherwise i have never used this function ever or in my current plugin but still having issue in running my code.

Comment: which file is this code in? Has the file been included twice?

Comment: no this file is not included twice at all, its being used in the beaver builder custom module extention's frontend.php file ... it it was twice then what about for all other functions being used in my plugin ???

Comment: have u tried by altering the name of the function ?

Comment: yes i did but its invain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just check it's already loaded once. Your plugin probably loads these actions when it's called and then load again your function when it calls your module. Like :

```
<?php 
// We check first if the function wasn't declared earlier : 
if(!function_exists('gt_footer_script')) :
// Then we load it
function gt_footer_script(){
?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    if ($('#gt-lightgallery_v<?php echo $gt_filter_counter; ?>').length) {
        $('#gt-lightgallery_v<?php echo $gt_filter_counter; ?>').lightGallery({
            selector: '.gt-gallery-box',

        });
    }
    });
</script>
<?php 
} 
endif;
// If the function already exists, no issue to run this code : 
add_action('wp_footer', 'gt_footer_script');
?>
```

Comment: Ohhh shit ... how can I forget all those PHP just in a hurry ... thanks a lot for pointing that out :)

Comment: No problem ! ;)